# How do I get a production build of next.js app onto github?? In over my head

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So i started customizing this template, https://github.com/jkytoela/next-startd, and am trying to get it to run on github and in a production build.  Only thing I've messed with before this is create-react-app so Im in a bit over my  head right now.

The normal steps I've taken , npm run deploy arent working.  I dont need a server setup or anything for my purposes.  The last thing Ive tried is to "next export" the app and to create a static HTML version, but Im still not sure what I'm doing.

Anyway any advice to get this thing done would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices first is using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) or use hosting service that support next js hosting like ([netlify](https://www.netlify.com/),[vercel](https://vercel.com/),etc) those are free but with limits